# Retrieve image from sqlite3 and display in Kivy image widget - ValueError

Tags: python, image, sqlite, kivy, kivy-language

**REQUIREMENT**

I'm trying to retrieve an image from Database and set this image to kivy image widget, this operation throws a ValueError, unsure of the cause. Welcome any inputs.

Database: Sqlite3

Table name: Users

Columns: UserID, UserName, UserImage

```
   def populate_fields(self): # NEW
      # Code retrieves text data and display in textinput fields here.

      # STEP 1: RETRIEVE IMAGE
      connection = sqlite3.connect("demo.db")
      with connection:
          cursor = connection.cursor()
          cursor.execute("SELECT UserImage from Users where 
          UserID=?",self.data_items[columns[0]]['text'] )
          image = cursor.fetchone()
          data = io.BytesIO(image[0])

      #STEP 2: SET OUTPUT TO IMAGE WIDGET
          self.image.source = data # ---> triggers an Error
```

**ERROR TRACEBACK:**

```
self.image.source = data
   File "kivy\weakproxy.pyx", line 33, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__setattr__ (kivy\weakproxy.c:1471)
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 478, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__ (kivy\properties.c:5572)
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 513, in kivy.properties.Property.set (kivy\properties.c:6352)
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 504, in kivy.properties.Property.set (kivy\properties.c:6173)
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 676, in kivy.properties.StringProperty.check (kivy\properties.c:8613)
 ValueError: Image.source accept only str
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After execution of `io.BytesIO()`, `data` is in Bytes. Use Kivy [CoreImage](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.core.image.html) and `texture` to convert `data`.

Replace

```
self.image.source = data
```

with:

```
self.image.texture = CoreImage(data, ext="png").texture
```

[Image source](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.image.html#kivy.uix.image.Image.source)

> ```
> source
> ```
>
> Filename / source of your image.
>
> source is a [StringProperty](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.StringProperty) and defaults to None

## Output

[image: Img01]
[image: Img02]

Answer (score 0):

Ikolim's answer is good but to be more specific,
If you want to display a binary image directly into kivy you can simply work with io module (import io) and kivy image module (kivy.uix.image)

Check this code:

```
from kivy.uix.image import Image, CoreImage
import io


binary_data= #binary img extracted from sqlite

data = io.BytesIO(binary_data)
img=CoreImage(data, ext="png").texture

new_img= Image()
new_img.texture= img
```