# letting the user upload a picture to my kivy app

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I started this week my first app in kivy platform.
One basic functionality I want to have is the ability to let the user upload a picture to the app and then storing it in my SQLITE3 DB .
All the solutions I found was how to show an image and not how to let the user upload one as input
After a long search on the web I haven't found any solution to my problem.

Thx for the help!

Comment: Is there anything you have previously tried? Can you show us minimal code for getting a picture from the desktop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve image from sqlite3 and display in Kivy image widget - ValueError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51758975/retrieve-image-from-sqlite3-and-display-in-kivy-image-widget-valueerror)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve data from db set to textinput fields and image widget in kivy for a multiscreen app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51615388/retrieve-data-from-db-set-to-textinput-fields-and-image-widget-in-kivy-for-a-m)

Comment: The problem is that I want the user to upload a pic using the GUI and then insert it to the DB and to the opposite.

Comment: @ikolim I dont want to do as u suggested (reading from DB and then displaying) I want to let the user upload an image and save it to my DB

Comment: @Yoavbanazar: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I cleared the problem by using file viewer and the selection attribute of him