# Display Image from Mysql directly to kivy window

Tags: python, kivy

I have checked out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51758975/retrieve-image-from-sqlite3-and-display-in-kivy-image-widget-valueerror) but it does not seem to explain clearly what is happening in order to display images directly from mysql db to a kivy window directly, assuming we already have the blob data from mysql in a variable called loaded_Image.

How can we display loaded_Image into window? {Preferably using a dynamic Image Widget and not from .kv file}

Please help if you have accomplished this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out to the best of my understanding

First load an image in form of blob data using normal mysql python and store in a variable, my case called image, you convert it as below to data then add data to CoreImage

```
image = value[9]
data = io.BytesIO(image)
img = CoreImage(data, ext="png").texture
```

Make sure you use this for your import

```
from kivy.uix.image import Image, CoreImage
```

Next ensure you add a default image within your project folder and call it using widget as follows

```
widget = Image(source = 'a.jpg')
```

Set the texture of widget to img, then add it to your target widget or parent

```
 widget.texture = img
 target.add_widget(widget)
```

The full working code like below:

```
image = value[9] #Add your data
data = io.BytesIO(image)
img = CoreImage(data, ext="png").texture
widget = Image(source = 'a.jpg')
widget.texture = img
target.add_widget(widget)
```